# Remove list entries containing multiple conditions

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, filepath

I have list of paths as strings

`>>> p = ['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/two/foo.txt', '/path/three/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt`]

I know I can remove an entry containing a word from the list using something like

`>>> p = [x for x in p if 'two' not in x]`

`>>> p`

`['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/three/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']`

However, this doesn't seem to work

`>>> p = [x for x in p if 'two' or 'three' not in x]`

`>>> p`

`['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/two/foo.txt', '/path/three/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt`]`

How can I remove all entries in `p` containing `two` or `three`?

Note, I am pull values `two` and `three` from separate keys in a dict so it might not be simple to create a single list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
p = [x for x in p if 'two' not in x and 'three' not in x]
```

Comment: This seems to be the ticket

Comment: Yes, just doing some testing

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all` with a generator expression:

```
values = ('two', 'three')
p = [x for x in p if all(i not in x for i in values)]
```

A better idea is to extract the specific folder and compare it to a `set`. Your example is straightforward since you are only interested in the second directory:

```
values = {'two', 'three'}

L = ['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/two/foo.txt',
     '/path/three/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']

res = [i for i in L if i.split('/')[2] not in values]

print(res)

['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

`p = [x for x in p if 'two' not in x and 'three' not in x]`

In Python, you have two separate Boolean statements: `'two' in x` and `'three' in x`. The syntax you were using does not work because Python is unable to recognize that syntax as two separate Boolean statements.

Comment: This is helpful but per `Ayoub Laazazi` I think I should be using `and` not `or`

Comment: Yup, you're right. I edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex. --> `re.search(r"(two|three)", x)`

**Demo:**

```
import re
p = ['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/two/foo.txt', '/path/three/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']
p = [x for x in p if not re.search(r"(two|three)", x)]
print(p)
```

**Output:**

```
['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

**@afg1997**, you can also continue with your own approach just by replacing **or** with **and** and with a little modification in your code as follows.

```
>>> p = ['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/two/foo.txt', '/path/three/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']
>>>
>>> [x for x in p if not 'two' in x and not 'three' in x]
['/path/one/foo.txt', '/path/four/foo.txt']
>>>
```